# How to stored a variable in asyncstorage?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I currently learning react-native.

I am trying to stored a variable into asyncstrorage in scriptone.js and calling it in scripttwo.js

But i failed to stored the variable in scriptone.js

What i have import in scriptone.js:

```
import React, { Component, BackAndroid } from "react";
import { AsyncStorage } from 'AsyncStorage';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Image, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Alert} from "react-native";
```

This is part of my code in scriptone.js

```
class SettingScreen extends Component {
  state = {
      a: '70',
      b: '',
      c: '',
    }; 

onPressButton = () => {
      if (this.state.a == this.state.aa) {     
        this.setState({ b: this.state.a });
        this.storeData();
      }
       else {
        Alert("Try Again");
      }
    }

   storeData(){
        const {a} = this.state;
        let  mynum : a;
        AsyncStorage.setItem('array',mynum)
        Alert("Saved");
   }

...
```

The error display :

```
"undefined is not an object(evaluating '_AsyncStorage.AsyncStorage.setItem')
```

May I know what the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: AsyncStorage is part of the core library, so you should import it from "react-native". Are you using some other library?

Comment: Whether you are using React-Native, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage, or Expo, https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/asyncstorage, the way to import `AsyncStorage` is the same `import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'` Perhaps if you shared your `package.json` and more of the code of your component then it may shed more light into why `AsycnStorage` is not working.

Comment: I have import the AsyncStorage from react-native. The error gone but i not sure is the variable stored in the asyncstorage. Btw, Thank you @JJJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## AsyncStorage

Usually to use AsyncStorage you first import it at the top of you file, the documentation says that you should import it as follows:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
```

Which you can see here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage

Obviously you should **remove** the previous import statement

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'AsyncStorage';
```

as leaving it in will cause name conflicts.

## Saving to AsyncStorage

Saving to AsyncStorage is an asynchronous task so you should use an `async/await` function that means you should update your `storeData()` function. You can see the documentation https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage for how you should do this.

```
storeData = async () => {
  const {a} = this.state;
  let  mynum = a;
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('array', mynum)
    Alert("Saved");
 } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
 } 
}
```

## Setting state

Next it looks like you could be getting yourself into a race condition when you're setting the state. It takes time for setState to set the item to state. So when you call

`this.setState({ b: this.state.a });`

the state may not have actually been set by the time you call

`this.storeData();`

leading to the wrong value being stored in AsyncStorage.

To over come this there is a couple of ways you could handle this

1. Use setState with a callback
2. Pass the variable to store as a parameter to `this.storeData()`

#### Use setState with a callback

This article goes into quite some detail about using setState with a callback https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296 however you could refactor your `onPressButton` to something like this

```
onPressButton = () => {
  if (this.state.a == this.state.aa) {     
    this.setState({ b: this.state.a }, async () => { await this.storeData(); });
  } else {
    Alert("Try Again");
  }
}
```

This will guarantee that `this.storeData()` won't be run until the state has been updated.

#### Pass the variable to store as a parameter

This requires refactoring the `storeData()` function to take a parameter

```
storeData = async (mynum) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('array',mynum)
    Alert("Saved");
 } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
 } 
}
```

Now to use this function we have to update your `onPressButton`, Notice that we pass the value that we want to store to `storeData` that means we no longer have to access it from state inside `storeData`

```
onPressButton = async () => {
  if (this.state.a == this.state.aa) {     
    this.setState({ b: this.state.a });
    await this.storeData(this.state.a);
  } else {
    Alert("Try Again");
  }
}
```

## Retrieving from AsyncStorage

This is also an asynchronous task and requires an `async/await`. To get the string that you stored all you have to do is pass the correct key to the `retrieveData` function

```
retrieveData = async (key) => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
      // do something with the value
    }
   } catch (error) {
     // Error retrieving data
   }
}
```

Comment: Are there any specific reasons as to why the keys are set static? Even in the documentation, methods are making requests for a default key. The setter examples are done in a way they always either create or update data given a default key. See [API documentation](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/api#getitem) for more details. The application works by giving dynamic values as well, but I feel like I might be missing something.